# Discrepancy between User page and League page reputation totals

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-leagues

I was recently poking about and noticed that there is a discrepancy between the reputation shown on the [site:users](https://serverfault.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year) page and the [Stack Exchange League](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/2/year/serverfault) page.

For me, the site shows I have 9507 for the year and the league shows I have 9950. The monthly and quarterly totals differ too. Other player have similar discrepancies.

Why is there a discrepancy ?

Comment: In addition, the user page reputation is 'live', e.g. updates during the day, the league reputation is set once a day at 00:00 UTC.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Note that I'm talking about annual, (quarterly and monthly) and that my total in the league is greater than the site (which is the opposite of the apparent dupe). Also, I haven't played hard for some time so a discrepancy of 443 is unlikely to be attributable to the time that the updates are run or caching. Before posting I also checked my voting history for 'private' changes and they are nowhere near 443. Please reopen this question as the dupe does not appear to answer it.

Comment: This is a known issue, and the difference can easily be 443. Make sure you include *deleted* posts too. There is a 300-or-so discrepancy between my yearly-league amount and the Stack Overflow user pages, for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Surely deleted posts would have the opposite effect to what we're seeing (as per the not dupe) ?

Comment: IIRC reputation earned for posts, once deleted, is not *subtracted* again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - only if the post is older than 60 days and has a score of +3 or more.

Comment: @ChrisF: I am talking about the reputation leagues; they ignore deletions for the totals over the year.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - ah. I don't really look at the leagues.